# Dynamically name objects in Java

Tags: java, android, object

I'm working on an Android project and I have a problem with creating objects dynamically.

For example, I want the events named like this:

*event1

*event2

...

I'm used to work in PHP, and I know I can't do this the same way in Java because the code has to be compiled before the program starts.

I don't know how many objects the program will have to make, as the data comes from an online database. I'm able to create 1 event if I put something like this:

```
Event event = new Event();
```

I would really like something to make an object for each event and store each object in a db4o database.

As I said, it's possible that there is only one event, but it is also possible that there are 100 events.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you need a collection of events.  Try putting them in a simple data structure like an [`ArrayList`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html) (similar to an array, but it can expand in size at run time).  This way you won't have multiple variables `event1`, `event2`, etc., but just one variable named `events` (or something similar) that holds as many objects as you need.

Comment: ok, I'll check it out. do you know if it is possible then to give each object a different name? as I will have to take them out of the array after and store them seperately in the db4o database. I'll try anyway.

Comment: @pieter You'd be able to take them out and store them one at a time, so there would be no need to have different variable names for each one. You could just re-use the same variable name.

Comment: ok thank you , it seems like it's working. sorry if this was a stupid question, but just learning to work with it !